# hibernate 5.2.2: ManyToOne first example

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, hibernate, maven

**the system that I'm implementing is composed of:** 
Eclipse Neon 4.6 + maven (integreted) + Hibernate 5.2.2 + Mysql (i use MySql Workbench 6.3)

**algorithm:** 
I tried to create this java application on eclipse:
a student entity and an address entity (the some address can be used for many students)

**info:**
I created only a htmanytoone schemas on mysql, and I want hibernate it to take care of creation and management of the entities on.
I hope there are no problems of continuity (I modified the code several times )

My project on eclipse:
[Package Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sojpV.png)

Student.java:

```
package  withMaven.hibernateMaven1;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {

    private long studentId;
    private String studentName;
    private Address studentAddress;

    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(String studentName, Address studentAddress) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
        this.studentAddress = studentAddress;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "student_id")
    public long getStudentId() {
        return this.studentId;
    }

    public void setStudentId(long studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }

    @Column(name = "student_name")//, nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getStudentName() {
        return this.studentName;
    }

    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Address getStudentAddress() {
        return this.studentAddress;
    }

    public void setStudentAddress(Address studentAddress) {
        this.studentAddress = studentAddress;
    }

}
```

Address.java:

```
package  withMaven.hibernateMaven1;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address {
    private long addressId;
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zipcode;

    public Address() {
    }

    public Address(String street, String city, String state, String zipcode) {
        this.street = street;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.zipcode = zipcode;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "adderess_id")
    public long getAddressId() {
        return this.addressId;
    }

    public void setAddressId(long addressId) {
        this.addressId = addressId;
    }

    //@Column(name = "address_street", nullable = false, length=250)
    @Column(name = "address_street")
    public String getStreet() {
        return this.street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    //@Column(name = "address_city", nullable = false, length=50)
    @Column(name = "address_city")
    public String getCity() {
        return this.city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    //@Column(name = "address_state", nullable = false, length=50)
    @Column(name = "address_state")
    public String getState() {
        return this.state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    @Column(name = "address_zipcode")//, nullable = false, length=10)
    public String getZipcode() {
        return this.zipcode;
    }

    public void setZipcode(String zipcode) {
        this.zipcode = zipcode;
    }
}
```

play.java: (the test main)

```
package withMaven.hibernateMaven1;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class play {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SessionFactory factory = new    Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session=factory.getCurrentSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            Address address = new Address("OMR Road", "Chennai", "TN", "600097");
            Student student1 = new Student("Eswar", address);
            Student student2 = new Student("Joe", address);
            session.save(student1);
            session.save(student2);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            transaction.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

hibernate.cfx.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class"> org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url"> jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://3306/htmanytoone?useSSL=false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>    
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <mapping class="Student" />
        <mapping class="Address" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

the pom.xml:  (I use maven because it is recommended, but I have no experience with it)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>withMaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>prova1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>proviamo maven</name>
    <description>primo utilizzo con maven</description>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.31</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

and now the console when i run play.java:

```
Sep 07, 2016 10:12:09 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.2.Final}
Sep 07, 2016 10:12:09 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Sep 07, 2016 10:12:09 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Sep 07, 2016 10:12:09 AM org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.stax.LocalXmlResourceResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration instead.  Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at any time.
Sep 07, 2016 10:12:09 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Sep 07, 2016 10:12:09 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Sep 07, 2016 10:12:09 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver] at URL [jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://3306/htmanytoone?useSSL=false]
Sep 07, 2016 10:12:09 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
Sep 07, 2016 10:12:09 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Sep 07, 2016 10:12:09 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
    at withMaven.hibernateMaven1.play.main(play.java:13)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:20)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:257)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
    at org.hsqldb.ClientConnection.openConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ClientConnection.initConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ClientConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.server.HsqlSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    ... 36 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use mysql, you have to Change this lines:

```
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/htmanytoone?useSSL=false</property>
```

Comment: I olso modify:    <mapping class="withMaven.hibernateMaven1.Student" />
          <mapping class="withMaven.hibernateMaven1.Address" /> for make move the code